# Complex Custom Promotion with MediaChase ECF G5 5.1

Tags: .net, e-commerce, episerver

We are trying to create a custom promotion for ECF G5 with fairly complex ruleset based on a customer requirement. It goes something like:

- Highest item at non-discounted price
- Other items discounted as per specific lookup tables based on their category, sub-category, market segment and or individual product discount (most specific wins)
- Highest item may have voucher % off discounts applied

How would you build this in ECF G5 5.1? I have read the documentation ( http://docs.mediachase.com/display/ecf51devguide/Custom+Promotion+Development+Explanation ) and I have a few questions:

1. Can a per-cart promotion affect individual line-items or must it operate on the entire cart? In our case we need to make decisions based on the whole cart whether this item is the most expensive product
2. Is there an easy G5 way to get "most expensive" product in the cart?
3. How can I control which products are voucher eligible?

Not looking for the "cleanest" or most architecturally sound solution, just looking to get it done! If you have any quick pointers that would be appreciated.

We are using .NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: There are a lot of questions in this thread, an answer would be massive. Please consider to break this apart and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Mediachase ECF can be upgraded to EPiServer Commerce, see more information here - http://www.episerver.com/About-Us/Press-Room/Press-Releases/EPiServer-Acquires-Business-of-e-Commerce-Solution-Provider-Mediachase-/
You can learn more about the latest version of the product here - http://www.episerver.com/Commerce/

Answer (score 0):

All of the above is possible. The best place to start is using one of the existing promotions. I will give quick pointers since as mentioned in the comments the full solution will involve quite a lot of development and testing. So here are the pointers:

1. Yes, it can, when you call AssignReward one of the parameters is affected entries, in your case it can be just that one particular entry.
2. Add another another rule that uses linq to get the highest priced item and save it to the constant.
3. You can define a custom attribute for an item and then use it to filter if it is eligible for the discount.

PS: I'm actually the one who wrote the promotion engine in ECF, I'm no longer associated with a company however and would recommend going to a new framework called VirtoCommerce (http://virtocommerce.com). Open source, more intuitive marketing engine, easily upgrade from ECF or EPiServer.

**Corrections:**

- the team of engineers that developed ECF till 2011 is no longer with a company
- i'm legally recognized creator of ECF and was an architect till 2011

Comment: EPiServer acquired MediaChase team from March, 2012. I saw ECF5.2, ECF5.3, EPiServer Commerce R1, R2, and R3 from that moment. I believe EPiServer Commerce (ECF) is under active development and still evolving.

Comment: ECF 5.2 is the last version me and my team released before leaving (this team designed and wrote more than 90% of all code from version 1 to 5.2 excluding frontend sample css and html) which included improvements to the Order system (mainly support for returns and exchanges). It was released in april 2011. I haven't seen the ECF 5.3, just service packs for 5.2. The next release was supposed to be consolidation of various meta models used in ECF (Business Foundation and Meta Data Model, half of ECF uses one and the other half uses the other) but it never happened.

Comment: You should probably disclose your relationship with VirtoCommerce here, as I see you have promoted it in a few places.

Comment: Sure Brad, not hiding it. I'm a creator of ECF (now EPiServer Commerce) and chief architect for VirtoCommerce.